# Finding days without events from a Timetree

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to find which days between 1st & 5th Jan, do not have any events associated. The full year time tree i.e. with days 1 to 365 do not preexist. Only those year-month-days exist where days have events.

Thought that the following should return [3, 4] as days 1, 2, 5 have Events, but not able to write a CYPHER that compiles :(

```
MATCH (year:YEAR {year:2017})-[:HAS]->(month:MONTH {month:1})-[:HAS]-(day:DAY)
    WHERE day.day >= 1 AND day.day <= 5
    WITH year, month, day
    ORDER BY year.year, month.month, day.day
    WITH COLLECT(day) AS days
    EXTRACT(day IN days | day.day) AS daysWithEvents
    RETURN FILTER(i IN RANGE(1, 5) WHERE i <> daysWithEvents)
```

Any guidance !

Answer (score 0):

Got it working

```
MATCH (year:YEAR {year:2017})-[:HAS]->(month:MONTH {month:1})-[:HAS]-(day:DAY)
WHERE day.day >= 1 AND day.day <= 5
WITH year, month, day
ORDER BY year.year, month.month, day.day
WITH COLLECT(day) AS days
RETURN FILTER(i IN RANGE(1, 5) WHERE NOT i IN (EXTRACT(day IN days | day.day)))
```